# findFragmentById returns a fragment that does not exist

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have the following 2 layout files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment android:id="@+id/list_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        class="MyListFragment"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

(w900dp)

```
<fragment android:id="@+id/list_fragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".3"
    class="MyListFragment"/>

<fragment android:id="@+id/content_fragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".7"
    class="MyContentFragment"/>
```

Then in my activity I have:

```
public class ReportActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.report);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        // Get the content fragment
        MyContentFragment contentFragment = (MyContentFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content_fragment);
        if (contentFragment != null) {
           // sometimes I get a handle to this fragment when I should not
           contentFragment.updateContent(//some content);
        }
    }
```

My problem is this.  When I start the app in landscape mode the width is wide enough to display both fragments. When I rotate to portrait it is no longer wide enough, the layout file without the content fragment is loaded.  However when I make a call to the fragment manager to get that fragment it finds it.  Then when I call update content that fails as the UI components inside that fragment no longer exist.

Why is getFragmentById returning a fragment that did exist, but no longer exists after device rotation?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is that your getFragmentById() call is returning the original Fragment - the one that is created when the app is started in landscape. It could be that when your activity is recreated during rotation, that Fragment is detached (but not destroyed) and then a *new* instance of it is added to the activity. Your getFragmentById() works, but the (original) Fragment that it returns has been detached so it has no inflated layouts - so the update content call fails.

Without more of your activity code, it's hard to pin the problem down. You should make sure that during activity creation, when you create and attach the fragment, that you first check and see if it already exists in the fragment manager.

```
....
Fragment frag = fragmentManager.findFragById(id);
if (frag == null) {
    frag = MyFrag.newInstance();
}
fragmentManager.replace(...,frag,...)...
```

I would actually use findFragmentByTag() because I find it easier to keep track of which fragment is which then. Just be sure to set a unique tag when the frag is replaced.

Comment: Thanks.  However I do not programatically create the fragments, android does it for me as they are in my layout file.  I.E. the reason I didn't post more activity code is because there is not more.  When you use the fragment tag in an xml layout file android creates/destroys the fragment.

Comment: You might want to try and manually handle it, since the framework does not seem to be doing a very good job.